# Type inference using generics in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have 2 functions with slightly different signatures:

```
const getValue = <TObj>(obj: TObj, key: keyof TObj) => {
  return obj[key];
};


const getValueMultiple = <TObj, TKey extends keyof TObj>(obj: TObj, key: TKey) => {
  return obj[key];
};

const result1 = getValue({ a: 1, b: 'some-text', c: true }, 'c');
// result1: string | number | boolean

const result2 = getValueMultiple({ a: 1, b: 'some-text', c: true }, 'c');
//const result2: boolean
```

I can't understand why in the first case result1 is of type `string|number|boolean` ( I expected it to be boolean), and why in the  second case  result2 type is inferred as expected.

I'd appreciate help or reference to the relevant documentation.

Comment: `key` is `keyof TObj`, which is `"a" | "b" | "c"`. If you use that to index into the object, you get `string | number | boolean`. Contrary to the second version, which has a generic parameter for `key` that lets it be "more specific" in a sense.

Comment: @merryweather  thank you , it actually makes a bit of sense for me now.

Comment: If that suffices, should @merryweather write an answer?

Comment: @jcalz That would be great to get an answer with  expanded explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, here's how TypeScript sees

```
const getValue = <TObj>(obj: TObj, key: keyof TObj) => {
  return obj[key];
};

// equivalent to

const getValue = <TObj>(obj: TObj, key: keyof TObj): TObj[keyof TObj] => {
  return obj[key];
};
```

```
const getValueMultiple = <TObj, TKey extends keyof TObj>(obj: TObj, key: TKey) => {
  return obj[key];
};

// equivalent to 

const getValueMultiple = <TObj, TKey extends keyof TObj>(obj: TObj, key: TKey): TObj[TKey] => {
  return obj[key];
};
```

At first you may think there is no difference but there actually is;

let's take TObj as { a: number, b: string, c: boolean }

```
TObj[keyof TObj] = TObj["a" | "b" | "c" ] = number | string | boolean
```

however, concerning TObj[TKey], since TKey is precisely one of "a" | "b" | "c" and TypeScript knows which one it is via the generic param `TKey extends keyof TObj`, you get a precise return type.